# What is the common design to return processed value and message to the user?

Tags: methods

When a method is called and must return a value for further processing, but for instance a message has also to be provided to the UI : what is the best or most common way to deal with those 2 outputs of a single method ?

ex :

```
public string exportStuffToFile() {
 (...)
 //do some work, that should be notified to the user
 //for instance, number of item processed, etc.  
 (...)
 return pathTotheFileCreated;
}
```

In this simple casse, How to transmit the "log of operations" and the Path ? 
Custom return Type ? Caller put himself as Delegate for the message ? Caller access a "Log" property after execution (bad design)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "custom return type", but that is just the first step toward a good design.

In object-orientation the "data" that is returned should be hidden (encapsulated). There should be no "accessors" to get at the various things in the result. Instead, the appropriate business-methods to work with the result need to be created. Display it to the user, continue work with the result, combine with other results, etc.

Functional-programming is essentially the same, but there are more readily available abstractions. We would say that there is a result (the path) and a "context", like a log of things that happened, etc. This is called a **functor** or a **monad**. The names are weird, but the concept is just as before to encapsulate the data and provide functions that you can use to work with the result.

Answer (score 0):

> How to transmit the "log of operations" and the Path ? Custom return Type ? Caller put himself as Delegate for the message ? Caller access a "Log" property after execution (bad design)

There are many ways to solve your problem. 
As you are talking about a "log of operations", I am inclined to use an actual logging mechanism that places the log messages in a location where the UI can access them when needed.

If the information for the UI is instead needed to update a progress indication (like a progress bar, showing also information on the percentage of work completed), then I would either use the logging mechanism or a callback/delegate mechanism for the updates to the UI. The reason for this is that this way the UI can receive live update while the function is still busy. That might not be a requirement today, but it is more likely to become a new requirement than that the caller suddenly needs intermediate updates.

As a final option, I would consider a custom return type with both pieces of information, but that is less suitable if the information is actually meant for different consumers.